# ractivejs unavailable as a framework on jsfiddle over ssl

Tags: jsfiddle, ractivejs

Apparently jsfiddle now requires https access in order to load frameworks. But the url it is using to load ractive is plain old http.

So... ractive devs, is it possible to make the ractive cdn accessible by  https? and if so, would you please make the url known in this jsfiddle github issue thread: https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/689.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have answered on the GH thread – we'll try and sort this out soon, but in the meantime the existing template fiddle still works and can be forked, as long as you stay on HTTP.

The URL is http://jsfiddle followed by .net/rich_harris/va6jU/. (I would paste it all in one go but SO has a blanket ban on JSFiddle links, even though their own code editor is absolute rubbish ಠ_ಠ)